jwt token is no longer valid when going from development to production
When running my project locally (in developement), the project works fine, and the token is valid and so on. But after running: npm build, which creates a version ready for production, the token is no longer valid (so it seems, from the error message below). The error below is when running in production. Running locally, I don't get this error.
InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: invalid base64 for part #2 (base64 string is not of the correct length)
    at on (index.js:49:15)
    at ShowAdmins.jsx:57:39
    at async i (ShowAdmins.jsx:44:24)

Below is the code that is referred to in the error message above.
await fetch("/api/getAllAdmins", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(token => {
                const decodedAdmins = jwtDecode(token);
                const allAdmins = decodedAdmins.allAdmins;

                Array.isArray(allAdmins) ? setAdmins(allAdmins) : setAdmins([]);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .finally(setLoading(false));

Specifically, it is this part:
headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            }

When I check the localstorage in the browser, the token looks fine. This is what it looks like:
localStorage
Storage {_lr_id_: '{"userID":"2acf9816-9010-41ca-9919-6404eeb80793"}', jwtToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWNjZXNzI…I3MX0.6lPnOIwGvmUNwnGA3Maw4kju4DQpsKJBzurijt1Yaec', length: 2}
jwtToken
: 
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWNjZXNzIjp0cnVlLCJtZXNzYWdlIjoiQnJ1Z2VyZW4gYmxldiB2ZXJpZmljZXJldCIsImZvdW5kVXNlciI6eyJpZCI6NCwiZm9ybmF2biI6IlRpdG8iLCJlZnRlcm5hdm4iOiJQaGlyaSIsImVtYWlsIjoibXlfaXNpc0Bob3RtYWlsLmNvbSIsInBob25lIjoiNDA3NTU1OTciLCJyb2xlX2lkIjoyLCJkYXRlYWRkZWQiOiIyMDI0LTEyLTE0VDIzOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLCJsYXN0ZWRpdCI6bnVsbCwibGFzdGxvZ2luIjoiMjAyNC0xMi0xNVQyMzowMDowMC4wMDBaIiwiYWRkZWRieSI6MSwiZWRpdGVkYnkiOm51bGx9LCJpYXQiOjE3MzQ1MzE2NzEsImV4cCI6MTczNDUzNTI3MX0.6lPnOIwGvmUNwnGA3Maw4kju4DQpsKJBzurijt1Yaec"
_lr_id_
: 
"{\"userID\":\"2acf9816-9010-41ca-9919-6404eeb80793\"}"
length
: 
2

I tried changing the import of the jwt token from:
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';

to
import { jwtDecode } from "base-64";

but with no luck
Ps. It is important to note that the error is happening in the client. This call to the server: ("/api/getAllAdmins"... never happens, because the token seems invalid

This is a duplicate of the following question
I suggest you try out the solution provided and read the GitHub jwt-decode documentaion if needed
